# why is callback not working in nodejs with mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

I'm working with nodejs and mysql and my problem is that I need that the second function executes only when the first one has ended. I am not sure if I am using callbacks in the right way, because it is not working. Thanks for your help!

```
var rol;
                function first(callback) {
                    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
                        conn.query('select idTipoUsuario from tipoUsuario where tipoUsuario = ?', [req.body.rol], (err, sol) => {
                            console.log("FIRST");
                            console.log(sol);
                            rol = sol[0].idtipoUsuario;
                        });
                    })
                    callback()
                }

                function second() {
                    req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
                        console.log("SECOND");
                        conn.query('insert into usuario values ?', [req.body.idUser, req.body.name, req.body.password, rol], (err, user) => {
                            req.flash('useradded', 'User added!');
                            res.redirect('/adduser');
                        });
                    })
                }

                first(second);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I moved the `callback()` call just below `rol = sol[0].idtipoUsuario;`